# injecting retrieved lat and lon data as json into google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Inside angularjs controller I'm injecting dataApi which succesfully retrieves data from the server to the angularapp. I have problem inject that data (location longitude and latitude) in google map.

I am able to log those retrieved data to the console but again I'm having problem injecting into google map. When using hardcoded latitude and longitude data google map works fine.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', ['dataApi', '$stateParams', MyController]);

    function MyController(dataApi, $stateParams){
        var passedId = Number($stateParams.id);     
        var vm = this;      
        vm.locationId = passedId;
        var lat;

        var details = dataApi.getDetails(passedId).then(function(data) {
                vm.details = JSON.parse(data);      
                lat = vm.details.Latitude;      
                console.log(vm.details.Longitude); // prints to the console     10.897790   
            });
        vm.map = {
            center: {
                //latitude: 48.370545, //harcoded value works               
                latitude: lat,  // this prints error message    : 
                                // angular-google-maps:
                                // could not find a valid center property   
                longitude: 10.897790
            },
            zoom: 13
        };
        vm.marker = {}
    };    
})();
```

I

Comment: I'm not familiar with anguarjs, but as it seems you create the map outside of the `then`-callback(where `lat` is undefined, because the data will be requested asynchronously). Possible solution: create it map inside the callback.

Comment: true, that solved the problem.